# PHP mail - need to authenticate with server

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a PHP mail script and I need to authenticate with my host's SMTP server.  I believe I need to use a 3rd party mail class like XPertMailer, but I'm not sure how to set this up.

Here's my script:

//send email containing their password to their email address

```
mail($email, 'Forgotten Password', "Here is your password: ".$row['password']."\n\nThanks for using my website!!", 'From: support@foobar.com');
```

Comment: Storing the password in plaintext in the database. It's a [bad idea](http://blog.moertel.com/articles/2006/12/15/never-store-passwords-in-a-database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) Class ,

You can find a good [tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/php/phpfreaks-eric-rosebrocks-phpmailer-tutorial.html) here